# Automatically add a condition to all JpaRepository methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa

let's say i have a class `Task` in which I have field `boolean finished`. I also have an interface `TaskRepository` that extends `JpaRepository` in which there are all the methods. I want all these methods to query or update only records with `finished==false`. Is there a way to configure repository that way to do it automatically, or do I have to create all methods manually with `somethingAndFinishedFalse`?

Comment: And how would you save a Task that is finished...

Answer (score -1):

With aspectj you can set a kind of regex to intercept all classes that contains certain aspect like package/names/return types etc...

For example the code below will be executed when a class with the pointcut is called.

```
import org.aspectj.lang;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class JpaIntegrityValidator {

 @Before("within(com.business.jpa.repository.*)") // Aspectj supports a lot of conditions within, execution etc.
 public void onRepositoryPackage(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    // This wil be executed before, or after, or when exeption etc.
 }
```

Its only a sample, you can use Before/After / After Throw etc and more conditions ... try to investigate that lib, i think it is what you are looking for.

You can throw a exception when the joinpoint contains your task with flag false.